# Developpement Mode issue - syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING or '('

Tags: php

I am in developpement mode and I got the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING or '('  in /home/mywebsite/www/app.php on line 3
```

Here the code of app.php

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ApcClassLoader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';

// Use APC for autoloading to improve performance.
// Change 'sf2' to a unique prefix in order to prevent cache key conflicts
// with other applications also using APC.
/*
$loader = new ApcClassLoader('sf2', $loader);
$loader->register(true);
*/

require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';
//require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppCache.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
//$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

I had a look on internet to solve this probleme and usually updating php version is enough. But I checked and I use php 5.6.2

I use OVH as a serveur provider in production mode. I use also 5.6.2 version of php. here the .htaccess to use this version.

```
SetEnv SHORT_OPEN_TAGS 0
SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 0
SetEnv MAGIC_QUOTES 0
SetEnv SESSION_AUTOSTART 0
SetEnv ZEND_OPTIMIZER 1
SetEnv PHP_VER 5_6_2
```

But still I have this issue. while in local it works just fine.

Comment: Code which triggers the error?

Comment: We need some code to help.

Comment: I added the file which trigger the error, but cannot see where the error is. So I thought the php version was the problem. But even by setting php_ver to 5.6.2 I got an error

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running check_configuration.php ? It should tell you what you are missing or you have misconfigured.

Please note that

- development mode is accessible via app_dev.php, not app.php.
- setting "php_ver" is a method to choose which PHP version to use in a OVH environment, but it's not a way to upgrade PHP everywhere. What are you using as a development environment?

Comment: Right. here the following information I got : **You are running PHP version "5.2.17", but Symfony needs at least PHP "5.3.3" to run. Before using Symfony, upgrade your PHP installation, preferably to the latest version.** I do not understand because I write in the .htaccess SetEnv PHP_VER 5_6

Comment: Again, "SetEnv PHP_VER_5_6" is generally not enough to upgrade PHP. I looked for that variable and it seems to be used only by OVH before 2014, and I couldn't find the 5_6 anywhere ( http://guide.ovh.com/php5chezovh ). 
Where do you host your development version? Do you have a WAMP/LAMP stack?

Comment: I add an other file .ovhconfig as explained in OVH web site. Now I do not have the **"your are running PHP version "5.3.17"** but got 500 Internal Server Error when typing www.mywebsite.com

Comment: my developpement version is hosted in MAMP

Comment: Does the check_configuration.php return any other error? You should definitely read the Symfony deployment guide: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/tools.html

Comment: There are now only RECOMANDATION (so I guess this is fine, or at least that is not the cause of my issues) Here the 2 recommandations: **Your requirements file is outdated. Run composer install and re-check your configuration.
Set short_open_tag to off in php.ini***

Comment: I will investigate further. I come back here if I reallly cannot find a solution. THks anyway LinoLinux